# Developer console does not update code when changes are made in the frontend

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service, alexa-slot

I created a new skill from scratch and set up two intents and two slots. Previously deleted the HelloWorld intent that comes built-in. However, the HelloWorld intent appears in the code when building the model, not the other two intents I created.

I deleted the skill and started another one and set up the two new intents and two slots. I expected the code contained in the console to be congruent to the changes made using the frontend but I attained the same wrong code.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add more intents and slots, you have to change your code in "Code Tab" too. The source code in "Code Tab" is create by default, if you change anything(intent, slot), please update source code in "Code Tab".